Is there a way to express the solution of this problem only in term of the parameters?
This problem came today in my math mid-term test:

An individual can invest part of his wealth $w$ in two risky assets. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the invested amounts in said assets. It is known that, with probability of $\pi_1$ both assets will have a return of $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively; with probability $\pi_2$ the first asset will have a return of $r_1$ and the second asset will have no return; with probability $\pi_3$ the first asset will have no return and the second asset will have a return of $r_2$ and with probability $1-\pi_1-\pi_2-\pi_3$, none of the assets will have any return.
The maximization problem is formulated as follows:
$$\max UE(x_1,x_2)=\pi_1U(w+(r_1-1)x_1+(r_2-1)x_2)+\pi_2U(w+(r_1-1)x_1-x_2)+\pi_3U(w-x_1+(r_2-1)x_2)+(1-\pi_1-\pi_2-\pi_3)U(w-x_1-x_2)$$
$$ s.t. x_1,x_2 \ge0$$
where $U$ is a utility function that is strictly increasing
¿What are the conditions that must be fullfilled between the parameters so the individual decides to:
a) Do not invest in any of the assets?
b) Invest only in the first asset?
c) Invest only in the second asset?
Note: The three answers must be expressed in terms of the parameters of the problem

I think the constraint of $x_1+x_2\le w$ should be added but the teacher said it was not necessary. The first thing that came to my mind is to compare the expected values of each decision, for example, if $$UE(0,0)\ge \max \left\{ UE(0,x_2),UE(x_1,0),UE(x_1,x_2) \right\}$$ for any values of $x_1$ and $x_2$, then the individual will decide to don´t invest in any of the assets, but I´m pretty sure I would´ve get 0 points if I did this for all the items because it was an exam about optimization with constraints. However, I think my thinking process is still correct.
The only other way was to stablish the first order conditions for a maximization problem with non-negativity constraints and then compare all the cases where the restrictions are active or not, but the partial derivatives of $UE$ are in terms of $U'$,$\pi_1$,$\pi_2$,$\pi_3$,$r_1$,$r_2$ and $w$, not only $\pi_1$,$\pi_2$,$\pi_3$,$r_1$,$r_2$ and $w$ (which I´m pretty sure are the only parameters of the problem) since the form of $U$ is unknown. I ended writing very long inequalities that almost didn´t fit on the paper (which didn´t feel "right"); for example, if $$\frac{\partial UE}{\partial x_1} \lt 0 ,  \frac{\partial UE}{\partial x_2} \lt 0 $$
Then the individual will decide to don´t invest any of his money.
Is there a way to express the solution only in terms of $\pi_1$,$\pi_2$,$\pi_3$,$r_1$,$r_2$ and $w$?

The assets can never lose, just gain or break even?  And there is no riskless asset to invest in which will always earn something?   If those claims are true, I don't understand why we should ever decline to invest.  After all, there is only upside in investing, right?  Of course you can balance the investment as you like according to the return matrix.

I added the "risky" because I was traslating it as exactly as possible to don´t alter the problem to much because it has happened to me that my traslation is bad and the problem is hard to understand when I post it here. Maybe I should erase it.

Not sure what your point is.  If my two assumptions are correct (neither asset can ever lose, the only alternative is to earn a guaranteed $0%$) then it is obvious that $x_1+x_2=w$, right?  What would be the point of retaining an uninvested dollar?

I think the assumptions are false since, it they were true, then there is no need to find the necessary conditions for the events in each item to happen. Also, if all the wealth $w$ is invested, then it would have no money to consume other indispensable goods like food, medications, etc. And the problem is about maximizing the expected utility of the person, not the expected earnings

But we are given no information about any of those things, so how could we hope to answer the question?

I don´t know, that´s why I´m posting this question...

Well, if we need all the wealth to cover essentials then we should invest nothing.  If we have any investable wealth left over (after essential expenses are covered) we should invest $100%$ of it, for the reasons I gave.  As we have no information about the essential expenses, we have no hope of deciding whether there is any investable wealth to deal with.   I suggest asking your instructor for clarification.

@lulu - note that the expectation of utility expression uses $r_1 - 1, r_2 - 1$. I.e., the initially-invested money is lost, and $r_1, r_2$ must be $\ge 1$ for the investor to not lose money.

@PaulSinclair  Declaring that an asset has "no return" is not the same as saying the investment gets wiped out.

@lulu - I did not base my comment on any interpretation of words, but on the given expectation of utility.
